# Custom fonts not displaying in my development pods

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, bundle, custom-font

I'm using `Exo` fonts in my app. I loaded them properly in main bundle. I checked they are in the `Copy Bundle Resources`, and are added to the `info.plist`

I have few development pods, where I put all my app code other than AppDelegate.

In these development pods, when I design the UI on storyboard, I can see all the custom fonts show properly on the storyboard. But when the app is run, all the fonts revert back to system font, and I can't see my custom fonts on app.

Here is the pod spec for my development pod 'TestFont'

```
s.resources = 'TestFont/*.xib'
s.resource_bundles = {
   'TestFont' => ['Resources/**/*.{xib,storyboard,xcassets,strings,html,json}', 'Classes/**/*.{xib,storyboard,xcassets,strings,html,json,png,jpg,otf,ttf,html}']
}
```

How can I change this pod spec  to load fonts from Main bundle ?

Is there a better way to handle this situation other than dynamic font loading ?

I have many development pods, and I want them to grab resources from main bundle.

Comment: Hey are you able to fix that issue.. I am facing the same issue

Comment: I fixed it by registering them , and them I'm able to use them.